# IBM AppScan identified a password parameter that was received in the query string meaning

Tags: security, penetration-testing, bluemix-app-scan

I am trying to fix the issues in IBM AppScan results and I\m getting the flag:

**AppScan identified a password parameter that was received in the query string**

with this command showing in the screen

```
GET /myapp.com/?username=user&password=**CONFIDENTIAL 1** HTTP/1.1
```

and I’m 100% sure that I'm not sending critical information in query params or even get requests I was thinking the about that the app is sending the request it self and want's me to block it.

Am I right or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Most likely during your scan, during the login process, AppScan intercepted this request. If you want to validate this put the browser in development and login to your application. Have a look at the requests that are passing through and see if you can spot this one. Let me know the outcome and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite common for application vulnerability scanners to misinterpret login forms that use JavaScript to make login requests. I am guessing the HTML form does not explicitly declare the request method as POST. Assuming when a user actually makes a request with a browser, a POST request is made, it's safe to assume that AppScan is generating this request itself.

One more issue to consider, if you make the request to `https://myapp.com/?username=user&password=password@123`, does that return a session token? This is often considered a vulnerability as well if the server does not reject all `GET` requests even if a user crafts it manually.